# Saleor + Vue.js

Tags: django, saleor

By the default saleor uses React, but I want to make my E-commerce site with Vue (DRF + Vue). What should I do?
By the way I wanted to use the SSR for the SEO improving. Need I do it with Saleor and what the difference between saleor installation with vue and vue ssr.
Also I want to keep the saleor admin page, can I do it with vue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In saleor platform there are three applications "API", "Storefront", "Dashboard" and they are separate from each other, but Storefront and Dashboard obviously depend on api. So you can reimplement Storefront and Dashboard base on API.

If you want to improve SEO then nuxt.js(build top of Vue.JS) is better choice for you.

You need to set up the Nginx file for server-side rendering and no need to change on API. And to implement graphQL on nuxt or vue use Appollo it has lots of benefits.

Comment: I know that Saleor uses graphql, but I need to write back with Django REST Framework, can I do it?

Comment: Everything is doable, but it's not practical to do it. If you really need to do that then copy all models and rewrite all functionality by yourself.